# Infusionsoft DataService.query or find Contacts by tags

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I have a task to find Contacts by tags using InfusionSoft API. It's easy to grab data by existing ID, but what if I need to exclude some tags?

For example, is there a way to get Contacts with tag id 111, but skip contacts who has tag id 222?

I can see that in `ContactGroupAssign` table there is a field `Contact.Groups`, it has all tag ids, but I can't find a way to execute query `NOT LIKE`

Is it possible to use `NOT LIKE` in InfusionSoft's `DataService.query`? Or maybe there is another way to get Contacts by tags?

I use PHP SDK, but I don't want to manage data on my end. I know I can retrieve data and then remove some of it in `foreach`, but I'd prefer to make a better query request.

**Also:** is it possible to use OR/AND in queries? for example, `GroupId => 111||222`

Answer (score 0):

Infusionsoft API documentation has been updated, here's a list of all supported query operators: https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-query-a-data-table . Not equal and IN statements are supported.